# priority queue size is 0 but priority_queue top returns an element

Tags: c++

I came across this weird behaviour of priority_queue in c++ while solving a leetcode puzzle .
The priority_queue has a size of zero but on doing pq.top() it returns an element which is quite weird to me .

```
class Solution {
public:
    int lastStoneWeight(vector<int>& stones) {
        
        priority_queue <int> pq ;
        
        for(auto &it: stones){
            pq.push(it);
        }
           
        while(pq.size() >1){
            int x = pq.top(); pq.pop();
            int y = pq.top(); pq.pop();
         
            if(x>y){
                pq.push(x-y);
            }
            if(y> x){
                pq.push(y-x);
            }
        }
        
        cout <<"pq.size() is "<< pq.size() << endl;
        cout <<"pq.top() is "<< pq.top() << endl;
        if(pq.size() == 0){
            return 0;
        }
        return pq.top();
        
    }
};
```

When this code is run for input [2,2]
this is what I get on doing cout .
Note that i had two elements in priority_queue and i have popped out both elements .

```
pq.size() is 0
pq.top() is 2
```

Comment: If the queue is empty it's Undefined Behavior to use top()

Comment: Calling `top()` makes it call the [`front()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/front)  member function in the container. See what it says there: _"Calling `front` on an empty container is undefined_".

Comment: Why oh why doesn't `pop()` return a value? I've been wondering that for 30 years.

Comment: @user207421 I saw the (a?) rationale for this somewhere (forget where) - IIRC it's to make `pop` cheaper when you're not interested in the value being popped.  Do people actually do that much?  No idea.

Comment: @drescherjm you are right.

Comment: Please do put a check before accessing the `top()`

Comment: @PaulSanders And makes it more expensive when you are interested, as you have to call both `top()` and `pop()`. You're nearly always interested in the value, surely. Doesn't make much sense to me. But then the whole of STL is extremely poorly designed IMHO, and I remember thinking so when it first appeared in about 1992.

Comment: @user207421 Not really.  `top` returns a reference, whereas `pop` would have to return by value.

Comment: @user207421 It is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25035691/why-doesnt-stdqueuepop-return-value).

Answer (score 2):

As others have pointed out your code, specifically the second `cout` line, exhibits undefined behaviour. Why is that?

Have a look at what `std::priority_queue`'s [`top` does](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue/top):

> Reference to the top element as if obtained by a call to c.front()

(`c` here [refers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue/priority_queue) to the instance of the underlying container, which is `std::vector` by default).

`std::vector::front()` has [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/front) to say:

> Returns a reference to the first element in the container.
>
> Calling front on an empty container is undefined.

The rationale here is that `top` returns by `const_reference` and an empty container has no valid values it could refer to.

If you remove the second `cout`, your code will be fine.

---

A note on what value you get: This depends on the implementation of your compiler and the library that goes with it. As stated this is highly undefined behaviour. However, the typical implementation of a `std::vector` (remember, the underlying container) is to never release the allocated memory it uses. Even if you empty it.

So, since you are dealing with `int`s here, the last value that was at position `0` of the vector (i.e. `front()`) will be retuned despite having been destroyed. The destuction of an `int` is a noop, and the value remains unchanged in memory. It's still not a legal C++ program.

Answer (score 0):

Doing pop operation on an empty priority queue is an undefined behaviour and it can give anything as output.

Comment: Who are you quoting from?